# Assigning Values based on row value

Tags: r

I have a large vector (column of a data frame) where values containing integers 1 to 30. I want to replace numbers from 1 to 5 with 1, 6 to 10 with 5, 11 to 15 with 9...

```
> x3 <- sample(1:30, 100, rep=TRUE)
> x3
  [1] 13 24 16 30 10  6 15 10  3 17 18 22 11 13 29  7 25 28 17 27  1  5  6 20 15 15  8 10 13 26 27 24  3 24  5  7 10  6 28 27  1  4 22 25 14 13  2 10  4 29 23 24 30 24 29 11  2 28 23  1  1  2
 [63]  3 23 13 26 21 22 11  4  8 26 17 11 20 23  6 14 24  5 15 21 11 13  6 14 20 11 22  9  6 29  4 30 20 30  4 24 23 29
```

As I mentioned this is a column in a data frame and with above assignment I want to create a different column. If I do the following I have to do this 30 times.

```
myFrame$NewColumn[myFrame$oldColumn==1] <- 1
myFrame$NewColumn[myFrame$oldColumn==2] <- 1
myFrame$NewColumn[myFrame$oldColumn==3] <- 1
...
```

Whats a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `cut` (suppose what you mean by '...' is 10, 11, 12):

```
x4 <- cut(x3,
          breaks = c(seq(1, 30, 5), 30), right = F, include.lowest = T, # generate correct intervals
          labels = 4 * (0:5) + 1) # number to fill

# x4 is factor. We should convert it to character first then to the number
x4 <- as.numeric(as.character(x4))
```

Comment: I don't really understand how labels have 10,11 shouldn't it be c(1,5,9,13,17) etc.

Comment: sorry. I didn't get your logic.

Comment: `cut` is really a nice function to divide numeric vector into different intervals. I often use it to bin data.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
myFrame$NewColumn[myFrame$oldColumn > 0 & myFrame$oldColumn< 6] <- 1
myFrame$NewColumn[myFrame$oldColumn > 5 & myFrame$oldColumn< 11] <- 1
...
```

Or even better:

```
myFrame$NewColumn <- as.integer((myFrame$oldColumn - 1)/5)) * 4 + 1
```